# Error executing SQL script via SMO in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I have some code that loads a script to a variable, and then I pass the variable to an [SMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Objects)  object. I get the following exception:

> Exception calling "ExecuteWithResults" with "1" argument(s): "Execute
>   with results failed for Database 'Russell_Test'.  "

- $serverName is the server name.
- $databaseName is the database name.
- $createScript is the script that was read.

How can I fix this problem?

Below is the relevant portion of the code.

```
# Load Smo and referenced assemblies.
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo');
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc');
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO');
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended');

    Try{
        $server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $serverName;
        $db = $server.Databases.Item($databaseName);
        $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($createScript);
        $result | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile;
    }
    Catch
    {
        [system.exception]
        $_.Exception | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the content of variable $createScript, please?

Comment: Here is the code in the database script read in: `USE Russell_Test
GO

create table scripttest (a VARCHAR(1))
GO`  The actual code that reads this in is: `$createScript = Get-Content $scriptFile.FullName | Out-String`

Comment: Try this simple CREATE statement: create table scripttest (a VARCHAR(1))

Comment: If you're using the Russsell_Test in $databaseName then skip that and the go.  Just run the create table statement.  Leave the final go off as well. If $results still comes back empty try "$result.Tables |Out-File ..." and see what you get.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko That did allow it to work.  The problem is I need to have multi-line scripts with GO in place.  That is why I was using SMO.  Do you know the solution?  Thank you.

Comment: @Bruce This was an example script the scripts I run will have GO statements in them and I don't want to modify them.  My understanding is SMO will handle this.

Comment: SMO does not and never did handle `GO`. The `GO` command is not a SQL command it is a Management Studio (SSMS) command and is implemented by it and SQLCMD (it's command-line interface) only. If you want to handle `GO`, then you will have to implement the code (powershell or otherwise) to cut up the script into separate batches on every `GO` yourself.

Comment: GO is a SQL Batching statement. See my answer on how to Batch instead of fail cryptically.

Comment: Also, if you get an error with SMO, use `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` and keep adding another .InnerException until you get real information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  Ultimately the SMO option would not work so I did this solution:

```
# Deploy table update scripts
$createScript = Get-Content $scriptFile.FullName | Out-String
################# Script execution to capture errors/messages/warnings ##################
        $createScriptList = [regex]::Split($createScript, '\bGO')
        $cn2 = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=$serverName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;Connection Timeout=600;Max Pool Size=10");
        $cn2.Open();
        foreach ($cSL in $createScriptList)
            {
                Try{
                $cmd = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($cSL, $cn2);
                $cmd.ExecuteScalar() | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile;
                }
                Catch
                {
                    [system.exception]
                    $_.Exception | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile
                }
            }
        $cn2.Close();
###############################################################################################
```

Comment: Really excellent sample. May be suggest a little improvement: 

`$createScriptList = [regex]::Split($createScript, '\bGO[^\S]')`

for string like with values 'GOAHead' or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do it:

```
# If we cast $Content as a [String], all the newlines are lost
# If we don't cast it, it becomes an array and batching breaks
$Content = (Get-Content $SqlScript) -join [Environment]::NewLine

# When using GO, we must set it up as a StringCollection, not a List or Array
$Batch = New-Object -TypeName:Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$Batch.AddRange($Content)
$result = $Database.ExecuteWithResults($Batch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) cmdlet. This cmdlet allows you to run T-SQL code or commands supported be the **SQLCMD** utility.

```
Try{
    Invoke-SqlCmd `
    -Query $createScript `
    -ServerInstance $serverName `
    -Database $databaseName `
    -ErrorAction Stop `
    }
    Catch
    {
        [system.exception]
        $_.Exception | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outputFile
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would capture all the errors based on my past research.  That said using Invoke-SqlCmd is a no go as I've had issues loading the sqlps module in all the environments the script are started from.

Comment: The -ErrorAction Stop ` parameter will help you to catch errors. The answer has been updated